# Updating items in a list from a blocking source asynchronously

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-core

This is a Windows forms application.

`this.Server.GetLogMessages()` will block if there are no messages to get, so I want this in a separate thread. I'm putting the messages into a `ConcurrentStack` and then pulling them out on the main thread to output them.

Here is the respective code:

```
private async Task UpdateLogs()
{
    var logMessages = new ConcurrentStack<string>();

    // assign to `_` to avoid warning
    var _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await foreach (var message in this.Server.GetLogMessages())
        {
            logMessages.Push(message);
        }
    }, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);

    await foreach (var message in GetMessages())
    {
        // don't update the UI if task is canceled
        if (this.CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }

        this.textLogs.AppendText($"{message}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }

    async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetMessages()
    {
        var message = String.Empty;

        while (!this.CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            while (!logMessages.TryPop(out message))
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }

            yield return message;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but seems as if it could be better/cleaner somehow.

Comment: _this.Server.GetLogMessages() will block if there are no messages to get_ means that the method is not properly implemented. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Have you considered to use DataFlow for this problem?

Comment: @aepot It may be able to be fixed. That is a different issue though.

Comment: @PeterCsala I have not heard of that. What is it?

Comment: @rhughes [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) you can find an introduction article and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782) you can find a couple of good examples for the basic building blocks.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: @aepot It seems so. I haven't tested it yet sorry. I will let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My try to simplify and prettify the method.

Avoid using globals in async code, pass Token as argument.

```csharp
// optimized out async State Machine
private Task UpdateLogsAsync(IProgress<string> status, CancellationToken token) => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await foreach (var message in this.Server.GetLogMessages().WithCancellation(token))
    {
        status.Report(message);
    }
}, token);
```

Usage

```csharp
// synchronized callback. Create new in UI Thread and its body will be always executed there.
IProgress<string> status = new Progess<string>(message =>
{
    this.textLogs.AppendText($"{message}{Environment.NewLine}");
});
try
{
    await UpdateLogsAsync(status, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    status.Report(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You can take advantage of the `WithCancellation` method.

Comment: @PeterCsala `this.Server.GetLogMessages().WithCancellation(token)`? Sorry, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, as long as the `GetLogMessages` returns with an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` then you can use the `WithCancellation` [extension method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.withcancellation?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to pass the ct to the async enumerator. For further details please check the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300816/13268855).

Comment: @PeterCsala got it, thank you! Updated the answer.

Comment: In this case there is no need to explicitly call this:`token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`